# Add UserId to database on successful login in Auth0

Tags: asp.net-core, auth0

That is the sample code provided by Auth0:

```
        public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
    {
        var authenticationProperties = new LoginAuthenticationPropertiesBuilder()
        .WithRedirectUri(returnUrl)
        .Build();

        await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync(Auth0Constants.AuthenticationScheme, authenticationProperties);
    }
```

Question is - how can i use my own method, for example _userService.CreateUser(guid Id) in here, to create new user (with only one property - id obtained from Auth0) on db? I need that for a lot of things in my application (for example to bind user content to user by this id, and then by Auth0 obtain his name etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnTicketReceived event in the AddJwtBearer configuration in your Startup file.

First, you need to add the AddJwtBearer configuration in your Startup.cs file:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = Configuration["Auth0:Authority"];
    options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:Audience"];

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = async context =>
        {
            var userId = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;

            // Call your method to create a user with the userId
            await _userService.CreateUser(userId);
        }
    };
});
```

Then in your AuthController, you can add the AuthenticationProperties to pass the returnUrl to the OnTokenValidated event:

```cs
public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")
{
    var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = returnUrl
    };

    await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("Auth0", authenticationProperties);
}
```

With these changes, when a user logs in successfully with Auth0, the OnTokenValidated event will be triggered and the CreateUser method in your _userService will be called with the userId obtained from the token.

Comment: Thank You, will try it later. Next question - is that an good approach, to store just userId, and then, when for example i want to show list of all users content with theirs names, just get usernames from Auth0 by this clientId?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can use the Auth0 Management API to retrieve the user's profile information from Auth0 using their userId. By doing this, you can reduce the amount of sensitive data stored in your application's database. Additionally, it's important to retrieve the user information from Auth0 each time you need it to ensure that your application always displays up-to-date information.